# Typescript assign value for keyof not working

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem: 
  - I do not assign for value of variable **temp** as code below 
 Please, how to assign value to variable **temp** 
Following code below:

```
interface Base {
      a: number;
      b: number;
      c: string;
 }

interface Child extends Base {
  d: string;
}

const data: Child = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: "1",
  d: "2"
}

function check<T extends Base>(obj: T, key: string) {
  const keys: any[] = Object.keys(obj);
  type dataTypes = keyof T;
  for (let m in keys) {

    // error: 
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.
    //  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"
    const temp: dataTypes = m; //error

  }
}

function test(data: Base) {
  check(data, "d")
}
```

Comment: `keys` is of type `string[]` not `dataTypes[]`

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]`, that's why `m` is a string, but `dataTypes` is `"a" | "b" | "c"` ([union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types)), i.e more restrictive. So you can't assign a string to a variable of type `"a" | "b" | "c"`.

The solution is simple: don't use `Object.keys(obj)`:

```
function check<T extends Base>(obj: T, key: string) {
  type dataTypes = keyof T;
  for (let m in obj) {
    const temp: dataTypes = m;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `for (let m in keys) {` by `for (var i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {`

```
for (var i=0; i< keys.length; i++) {

    const temp: dataTypes = keys[i]; //no error

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```js
const temp = m as keyof T;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27602953)

Comment: @Burimi: This looks like [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) to me. It would definitely benefit from more explanation, and it's not entirely clear to me how it differs from similar answers with slightly different syntax, but it's nevertheless an attempt to answer.